# Junit: Database Test Connection Function Test

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have written a function that expects database connection details like jdbcUrl, username and password and tests whether the connection with given details is successful or not.

```
    public boolean testConnection(String jdbcUrl, String userName, String password) {

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, userName, password)) {

            if (conn != null) {
                return true;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I am not understanding how to actually test it with Junit. Looks like static functions cannot be mocked. Any help would be great.

Comment: In what context are you trying to test this? For integration tests, you're usually running against a test db, in which case it doesn't really make much sense to test if you can connect since you should have test cases actually trying to get data, which will fail. For a unit test, you don't want to create a db connection at all.

Comment: @daniu I am looking for unit test

Comment: 1. You CAN mock static methods since Mockito > 3.4.0 2. As @daniu said, mocking jdbc calls is a dead end. You can do it for a simple function like shown above, but an integration test for your DAOs will give you more bang for a buck - it is less work and will detect more errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of Mockito.

```
    @Mock
    private DataSource ds;
    @Mock
    private Connection con;
    @Mock
    private PreparedStatement stmt;
    @Mock
    private ResultSet rs;


 @Before
 public void init() throws Exception {
       Assert.assertNotNull(ds);
       Mockito.when(c.prepareStatement(any(String.class))).thenReturn(stmt);
       Mockito.when(ds.getConnection()).thenReturn(conn);

​}
```